# Laravel Custom Facade Mock/Fake

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I'm transitioning to using facades for any integrations for my projects. At this point, it seems more manageable. Controversial I know.

I want to know what the best way to acheive the "fake()" method that is shipped with Laravel Facades for my own Facades.

This isn't shipped with the Facade extension, so is this not advisable? You only get access to "shouldReceive" but this means I have to make an assertion, which I don't always want to do.

Ideally, I'll fake each integration during testing so nothing gets through that I might have missed. So:

- Shopify::fake()
- QuickBooks::fake() or
- AnyIntegration::mock()

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Check the source code and do exactly the same. That is the best idea to follow, you will learn a lot